# Create ProgressBar while populating a TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview, progress-bar

I need to create a simple Progressbar while the TreeView loading itself from database and because its online-databse it takes some times to display the Form which contains this TreeView.

This is what i have done but don't know how/where to put "progressbar.PerformStep()" or happy to know how to do it.

```
private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String myConnectionString = "server=...";
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        String Sequel = "SELECT ...";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Sequel, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            parentNode = MainTreeView.Nodes.Add(dr["NODNAME"].ToString());
            parentNode.Tag = ...;

            PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["PARVAL"].ToString()), parentNode);
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void PopulateTreeView(int parentId, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    String Seqchildc = "SELECT PARVAL, SUBNODNAME, SUBNODVAL FROM subparentnod WHERE PARVAL=" + parentId + "";
    MySqlDataAdapter daChild = new MySqlDataAdapter(Seqchildc, conn);

    DataTable dtChild = new DataTable();
    daChild.Fill(dtChild);

    TreeNode childNode;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtChild.Rows)
    {
        if (parentNode == null)
        {
            childNode = MainTreeView.Nodes.Add(dr["SUBNODNAME"].ToString());
            childNode.Tag = dr["SUBNODNAME"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr["SUBNODNAME"].ToString());
            childNode.Tag = dr["SUBNODNAME"].ToString();
        }
        PopulateTreeView(Convert.ToInt32(dr["SUBNODVAL"].ToString()), childNode);
    }
}
```

Here is what i've done with other Form and using Progress-bar and Action.

```
public partial class frmWaitForm : Form
{
    public Action Worker
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public frmWaitForm(Action worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (worker == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        Worker = worker;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, 
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    private void frmWaitForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (frmWaitForm mFrmWaitForm = new frmWaitForm(RetriveDataFromDatabase))
            {
                mFrmWaitForm.ShowDialog(this);
            }

void RetriveDataFromDatabase()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn;
            MySqlCommand cmd;
         ...


        }
```

Comment: You would have to do this in a background thread in order to not lock the gui.  For a proper progress, you would have to know how many nodes are being added, otherwise, you would have to pick the marquee style.  In a BackgroundWorker, you would have a ReportProgress event where you would call the code to update the progress bar.  Generally, your ReportProgress call would be inside your loop.

Comment: You are executing one SQL query per node. You could probably optimize greatly the performance by fetching all data from `subparentnod` in a single query, and selecting the subset for each node using the LINQ [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) method (or using the old way of defining a [`DataRelation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-datarelations) between the DataTables).

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias thanks but now there is no time for optimization cause I'm C# beginner. maybe after performing the Progress-bar.

Comment: @LarsTech this cannot be done in a background thread, at least not easily, because the bulk of the work involves populating a UI element (the TreeView).

Comment: @LarsTech thanks. BackgroundWorker is completely new to me at this time. actually i've done my needs with void.System.Action for other treeView subnode child Form but this Form page has other story.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'll just disagree with you there.  The user wants a progress bar which means *something* is a long running operation here.  Adding nodes to the TreeView is not the time consuming part.

Comment: _Adding nodes to the TreeView is not the time consuming part._ Maybe yes, maybe no. Adding thousands of nodes __directly to the tree_ (instead of preparing them before adding the root nodes) does take a long time.

Comment: @TaW Then we get into the "does the user really need millions of nodes" argument.  Personally, I have a love/hate relationship with TreeViews.  As a developer, love them, as a gui component for the general public: way too cumbersome.

Comment: @TaW TreeView placed at 1st Form to open and there isn't anything before it. Maybe prgressbar cover that prepation.

Comment: @LarsTech assuming that you are right, and updating the UI is not the time consuming part, there is still the problem that multiple SQL queries and UI updates are intermingled together, and the OP does not want to refactor his code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Which is the problem.  The OP thinks a progress bar can just be added without any issues, but to make it work properly, refactoring is required.  And I agree with you, this would be much easier with a single database call.

Comment: If you've already solved the problem of displaying a `ProgressBar` with `frmWaitForm` then I'm not sure what the problem is? Why can't you reuse that?

Comment: @Joshua Robinson displaying Progressbar with System.Action in subNode TreeView. But i need Progressbar for TreeView.

Comment: @LarsTech it could be done in the UI thread by calling `MainTreeView.SuspendLayout()` at the start and `MainTreeView.ResumeLayout()` at the end, and calling `Application.DoEvents()` after each update of the progress bar to allow the repainting of the window. It is dirty as heck though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think you meant [BeginUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.8) and [EndUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.endupdate?view=netframework-4.8).  And yes, stay away from DoEvents.

Comment: @LarsTech you are right, `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` are the correct methods to prevent controls like `ListBox` and `TreeView` from redrawing repeatedly. `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` are for container controls. 